# RegEx for <a id="Some_Random_Text"/> in php

Tags: php, html, regex

I want to replace 
`<a id="any_text"/>` with `space` or `""`. I'm using

```
$a=preg_replace("/<\\/?a\\s|id(\\s+.*?>|>)/", "",$file);
```

but it only removes `<a`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest this regular expression:

```
/(<a\s+id="[^"]*"\s*\/>)/
```

This would result in that command:

```
$a = preg_replace('/(<a\\s+id="[^"]*"\\s*\\/>)/', '',$file);
```

Which leaves us with this little test script:

```
<?php
$subject = 'test-<a id="any_text"/>-test';
$pattern = '/(<a\\s+id="[^"]*"\\s*\\/>)/';
print_r(preg_replace($pattern, '', $subject));
```

And the output obviously is:

```
test--test
```

Comment: Sure it is. Regular expressions are no rocket science. I suggest you use some online regex tester for their development, they are a great help :-)